# Divide graph into subgraphs based on attribute of border vertices

Tags: python, algorithm, charts, networkx

### Finding Clusters in Directed Graphs with Specific Border Node Conditions

I'm working with a directed graph (DiGraph) in Python, using the NetworkX library. My graph consists of several nodes representing different positions (labelled "WITH" and "AGAINST") on various topics or categories (numbered 1 through 6). Some of these nodes have a special attribute (`special_attribute=True`), which plays a crucial role in my analysis.

#### Objective

I need to develop an algorithm to identify clusters within this graph under the following conditions:

- A cluster is a group of nodes that are strongly connected.
- The **border** or **peripheral nodes** of these clusters must have the `special_attribute=True` attribute. It's important to note that these border nodes can be part of multiple clusters.

#### Example Graph Structure

The graph has nodes like `1-WITH`, `1-AGAINST`, `2-WITH`, etc., with some having the `special_attribute` attribute set. A small example graph is shown below, with the red nodes having the special attribute
[image: example graph]

### Question

How can I implement an algorithm in Python that finds all such clusters in the graph, adhering to the condition that the clusters' border nodes have the special_attribute=True attribute? In the example above, the clusters would be

`4-AGAINST, 4-WITH, 6-WITH, 6-AGAINST, 5-WITH, 5-AGAINST, 2-WITH, 2-AGAINST`

and

`5-WITH, 5-AGAINST, 2-WITH, 2-AGAINST, 3-WITH,3-AGAINST, 1-WITH,1-AGAINST`

**Note:**
The actual graph I am working on has around **40.000** vertices and **70.000** edges.

Code to copy-paste for creating the graph above:

````
digraph = nx.DiGraph()
digraph.add_node('1-WITH')
digraph.add_node('1-AGAINST')
digraph.add_node('2-WITH', specialAttribute=True)
digraph.add_node('2-AGAINST', specialAttribute=True)
digraph.add_node('3-WITH')
digraph.add_node('3-AGAINST')
digraph.add_node('4-WITH')
digraph.add_node('4-AGAINST')
digraph.add_node('5-WITH', specialAttribute=True)
digraph.add_node('5-AGAINST', specialAttribute=True)
digraph.add_node('6-WITH')
digraph.add_node('6-AGAINST')


# Add edges 
digraph.add_edges_from([('1-AGAINST', '1-WITH'),('1-WITH', '2-WITH'),('1-WITH', '3-WITH'), ('2-WITH','4-AGAINST'), ('4-AGAINST', '5-AGAINST'),  ('4-AGAINST', '6-AGAINST'),  ('6-AGAINST', '6-WITH'),
                        ('6-WITH', '5-AGAINST'),  ('6-WITH', '4-WITH'),  ('5-AGAINST', '3-AGAINST'), ('3-AGAINST', '2-WITH'), ('3-AGAINST', '1-AGAINST'), ('3-WITH', '5-WITH'), ('4-WITH','2-AGAINST'),
                        ('2-AGAINST','1-AGAINST'), ('2-AGAINST','3-WITH'), ('5-WITH','4-WITH'), ('5-WITH','6-AGAINST')
])```
````

Comment: How do you define a "border" node?

Comment: If specialAttribute exists and is True, meaning that each cluster/group should be surrounded by nodes with this property(the red ones in the image).

Comment: Is this just a visualization issue, or do you mean that if you removed your "border" nodes, the graph would be partitioned into unconnected subgraphs with one cluster per subgraph?

Comment: This: " the graph would be partitioned into unconnected subgraphs with one cluster per subgraph?".

The end goal is to perform a demanding optimization problem on the graph, where the nodes with the specialAttribute can be seen as observations, and this logic would then make each group independent, this reducing computational issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This: " the graph would be partitioned into unconnected subgraphs with one cluster per subgraph?". The end goal is to perform a demanding optimization problem on the graph, where the nodes with the specialAttribute can be seen as observations, and this logic would then make each group independent, this reducing computational issues.

1. Induce a subgraph that does not contain your "special" nodes.
2. Determine the unconnected components.

```py
non_special_nodes = [node for node in digraph if "specialAttribute" not in digraph.nodes[node]]  
subgraph = nx.subgraph(digraph, non_special_nodes)
components = list(nx.connected_components(subgraph.to_undirected()))
print(components)
# [{'1-AGAINST', '1-WITH', '3-AGAINST', '3-WITH'},
#  {'4-AGAINST', '4-WITH', '6-AGAINST', '6-WITH'}]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Smart solution. I just need to add back the nodes with the specialAttribute to each component, but this should be an easy implementation.